# beginner q about console.log and functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a quick question about console.log in javascript. The following is the code I wrote:

```
var multiplied = 5;

var timesTwo = function(number) {

    var multiplied = number * 2;
    console.log(multiplied);
};

timesTwo(4);
console.log(timesTwo(4));
```

the first function call for "4" works perfectly, the second version, where I call the function through console.log, returns undefined. Is this because console.log only returns statements?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this because console.log only returns statements?

`console.log` doesn't return anything. It just logs its argument to the console. So you should return from your `timesTwo` the result of the multiplication:

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {
    var multiplied = number * 2;
    return multiplied;
};
```

and then:

```
console.log(timesTwo(4));
```

Remark: you have declared some `multiplied` outside of your function (in the global scope) which is never used. You probably don't need it because the `multiplied` variable that is used inside the `timesTwo` function is local to the function and the one that gets actually used in this example.

Comment: Just for precision : The problem is that the function `timesTwo` does not return anything contrary to the version of @Darin Dimitrov.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var timesTwo = function(number) {

    var multiplied = number * 2;
    console.log(multiplied);

return multiplied;
};
```

You need to return something.

Answer (score 0):

`timesTwo(4)` did not return anything. So `undefined` was logged in console.

**EDIT:** `console.log` does not return anything, only writes something in the console. Not all browsers have console (i.e. IE), so you should use:

```
if(window.console){

console.log(" log into console");

}else{

alert("alert as not console available"); // using the alert is up to you

}
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log() only prints stuff to the console, try using a return statement instead of console.log()

```
const timesTwo = function(number) {
    return number * 2;
};
```